# execute yii class methods in yii shell in the context of the yii app

Tags: yii

Is it possible to execute yii class or instance methods in yii shell.

Say for example, i want to print all the records of a table, the command for this is `Post::model()->findAll`. But can I execute this in the yii shell, in the context of the yii web app.

Also, is it possible to access the components of an yii application (like db) in the yii shell.

In short i could like to execute some yii methods in the context of the yii application (much like executing small javascript statements in the firebug console).

**Edit 1**
Found one solution as mentioned below:

```
php C:\xampp\htdocs\trackstar\protected\yiic shell C:\xampp\htdocs\trackstar\protected\config\main.php
```

and then execute the yii commands.

**Edit 2**

```
echo Project::model()->findByPk(3);
```

is giving error `object of class project cant be converted to string`. Is there any way to print or pretty print the yii objects in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Yii. It's a php questions. Anyways, you can try this -

```
var_dump(Project::model->findByPk(3));
    // or 
print_r(Project::model->findByPk(3));
```

or better still use CVarDumper from yii -

```
CVarDumper::dump(Project::model->findByPk(3);
```

Documentation on CVarDumper - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CVarDumper